# FillRectangle not filling with the exact color for the SolidBrush provided

Tags: c#, .net

I am filling a `Bitmap` with color:

```
// Assume we have something like: 
// Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(3, 2, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(color))
{
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
    }
}
```

However when I do something like `Bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0)` it will return a `Color` that is close -- but not identical -- to the color that I set in the brush. If I drop the alpha channel low enough on the `Color`, the RGB color channels will be zero. For example, `Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3, 4)` as the brush color will yield a bitmap full of `1, 0, 0, 0`. If I do `Color.FromArgb(11, 22, 33, 44)` then I get a bitmap with colors like `11, 22, 22, 44`. As such, my unit tests are breaking. since I can't get a direct match.

Is there a way I can get this to fill the entire rectangle quickly with the exact solid color I provide? Speed is important, this is in a somewhat hot loop in the program so doing `Bitmap.SetPixel(...)` is out of the question. I'd rather not do `unsafe` unless there is no other way.

---

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(3, 2, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3, 4)))
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height);
            }
        }

        var pixel = Bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interpolation artifact, Graphics.PixelOffsetMode will matter for this code.

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried every setting with `PixelOffsetMode` (and according to other SO posts, there's only really two, but I tried all of them just to be sure) to no success, and then tried messing with `SmoothingMode` combinatorically with `PixelOffsetMode` but to no avail. What other thing(s) am I missing?

Comment: You didn't post adequate repro code of course.  The pixel format of the bitmap matters too, I'd guess you have a 32bppPArgb bitmap.  Try it with 32bppArgb so the color doesn't have to be translated when the alpha component is < 255.

Comment: @HansPassant There's now a full MCVE at the bottom, even though the code is within 5 seconds of being reproducible in something like dotnetfiddle. As similar to the comment I had since the beginning of the post, I'm using 32bppArgb and not the P version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LockBits()` and set the colors in the memory:

```
public static Bitmap Fill(Bitmap bmp, Color color)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        bmp.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);  
    for (int i= 0; i< rgbValues.Length; i+= 4)
    {
         rgbValues[i] = color.A;
         rgbValues[i] = color.B;
         rgbValues[i] = color.G;
         rgbValues[i] = color.R;
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    return bmp;
}
```